# Auto-save in Atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor

Some code editors, such as WebStorm, have an option to auto-save when the editor loses focus. I've searched for an option like this in the Atom Editor but haven't found anything yet.

Does the Atom Editor have a setting that allows for auto-save of edited files when it loses focus? If so, where can this be set? If not, how would one go about writing a plug-in that does that?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Yes there is [auto save package](https://atom.io/packages/autosave). You can enable autosave in package settings.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if you're working on a new file and have yet to perform an initial save. If Atom crashes, or your Mac reboots, all is lost :-(

Comment: This doesn't work on MAC with Atom editor version 1.12.6

Comment: Remember to flag Enabled in Settings, as it seems to be disabled by default after installing... Ask me how I know.

Comment: In my opinion the fact that this is disabled by default is a bug.

Answer (score 25):

Just add this to your ~/.atom/config.cson

```
autosave:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: This worked for me. Also, apparently no plugin required. This should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: I have made the setting as suggested above in config.cson & also installed atom-beautify package. So my expectation was the python code will auto beautify, since auto save & beautification package is installed. But it does not happen. Only when I press CTRL + S will the beautification work. Anyway to get the code beautification to work with the above settings

Answer (score 23):

autosave-onchange much better alternative!

https://atom.io/packages/autosave-onchange

Answer (score 8):

There's also the [save-session](https://github.com/mpeterson2/save-session) plugin which makes Atom behave more like Sublime: the current state of each file is remembered across application instances. This is slightly different than the original request, but also extremely useful.

Comment: This package is now deprecated and included in Atom's core functionality (hooray!).

Comment: It'll asks to save when you swap pans (the save only seems to concern the pan config. If you choose no, the session/files will still be saved)

Answer (score 3):

It's late answer, but In case someone needs it.
`auto save package` save something when a it's lose focus or get close.
If you want auto save right after every type, You can install `autosave-on-change` by ChexWarrior. Check this [link](https://atom.io/packages/autosave-onchange). It will auto save right after every type. You can install it from package installer of `atom`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the auto-save feature is now [embedded in 1.8.0](https://atom.io/packages/save-session).

But doesn't always work. See issue [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/10044).

In order to use it, enable "Back Up Before Saving" in settings.

[image]

Comment: I think "Back Up Before Saving" is about making saving more robust, not about saving automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed the autosave and activated package but it does not work in atom.

I installed the autosave-onchange package, and it works perfect, I recommend it. . . The only difference besides that works well for me, is that you record at all times as soon as you make a change . . .